# jsTree not getting data from server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jstree

In my mvc application, I have used jsTree,

my view

```
                @{
                ViewBag.Title = "OnDemand";
            }

            <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/jstree.min.js"></script>

            <h2>OnDemand - Treeview</h2>
            <div id="demo1">

            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function($) { 


                    $("#demo1").jstree({
                        "json_data": {
                            "ajax": {
                                "type": "POST",
                                "dataType": "json",
                                "async": true,
                                "contentType": "application/json;",
                                "opts": {
                                    "method": "POST",
                                    "url": "/Treeview/GetAllNodes11"
                                },
                                "url": "/Treeview/GetAllNodes11",
                                "data": function (node) {
                                    if (node == -1) {
                                        return '{ "operation" : "get_children", "id" : -1 }';
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        //get the children for this node
                                        return '{ "operation" : "get_children", "id" : ' + $(node).attr("id") + ' }';
                                    }
                                },
                                "success": function (retval) {
                                    return retval.d;
                                },
                            }
                        },
                        "plugins": ["themes", "json_data"]
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

my controller

[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetAllNodes11(string id)
        {
            List G_JSTreeArray = new List();

```
        G_JSTree _G_JSTree = new G_JSTree();
        _G_JSTree.data = "x1";
        _G_JSTree.state = "closed";
        _G_JSTree.IdServerUse = 10;
        _G_JSTree.children = null;
        _G_JSTree.attr = new G_JsTreeAttribute { id = "10", selected = false };
        G_JSTreeArray.Add(_G_JSTree);

        G_JSTree _G_JSTree2 = new G_JSTree();
        var children =
            new G_JSTree[]
        {
            new G_JSTree { data = "x1-11", attr = new G_JsTreeAttribute { id = "201" } },
            new G_JSTree { data = "x1-12", attr = new G_JsTreeAttribute { id = "202" } },
            new G_JSTree { data = "x1-13", attr = new G_JsTreeAttribute { id = "203" } },
            new G_JSTree { data = "x1-14", attr = new G_JsTreeAttribute { id = "204" } },
        };
        _G_JSTree2.data = "x2";
        _G_JSTree2.IdServerUse = 20;
        _G_JSTree2.state = "closed";
        _G_JSTree2.children = children;
        _G_JSTree2.attr = new G_JsTreeAttribute { id = "20", selected = true };
        G_JSTreeArray.Add(_G_JSTree2);

        G_JSTree _G_JSTree3 = new G_JSTree();
        var children2 =
            new G_JSTree[]
        {
            new G_JSTree { data = "x2-11", attr = new G_JsTreeAttribute { id = "301" } },
            new G_JSTree { data = "x2-12", attr = new G_JsTreeAttribute { id = "302" }, children= new G_JSTree[]{new G_JSTree{data = "x2-21", attr = new G_JsTreeAttribute { id = "3011" }}} },
            new G_JSTree { data = "x2-13", attr = new G_JsTreeAttribute { id = "303" } },
            new G_JSTree { data = "x2-14", attr = new G_JsTreeAttribute { id = "304" } },
        };
        _G_JSTree3.data = "x3";
        _G_JSTree3.state = "closed";
        _G_JSTree3.IdServerUse = 30;
        _G_JSTree3.children = children2;
        _G_JSTree3.attr = new G_JsTreeAttribute { id = "30", selected = true };
        G_JSTreeArray.Add(_G_JSTree3);

        return new JsonResult { Data = G_JSTreeArray, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

but it does not hitting the controller

what is the issue with this code?

Comment: A bit offtopic, but consider upgrading to jstree v.3, it is a lot faster and more robust. Besides v.1 has not been supported for years.

Comment: @vakata when using jquery.jstree.js , it works and when using jstree.js it is not working

Comment: Treat v.3 as a different product - it has different options, etc - this is the reason behind the major version change (and skipping 2 completely). If you decide to upgrade - just read the repo readme file or jstree.com.

Answer (score 0):

data cannot be a function so dynamic data assignment based on selected node is not evaluated but you use assign url with a function to change parameter to pass to controller. you must use GET method to retrieve data from controller -

Try this

```
"json_data": {
                    ajax: {

                        "url": function (node) {
                            var url;
                            if (node == -1) {
                                url = "/Treeview/GetAllNodes11/?operation=get_children";
                            } else {
                                var id = $(node).attr("id");
                                url = "/Treeview/GetAllNodes11/?operation=get_children&id=" + id;
                            }
                            return url;
                        },
                        "type": "GET",
                        "dataType": "json",
                        "contentType": "application/json charset=utf-8",
                    },
                },
```